# Starting jupyter notebook from within python script for debugging

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

A standard way for debugging code in Python is to start the Python debugger at the line of interest in your source, i.e. you do:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

However, this isn't too useful if you need to debug image processing algorithms. Is there a way to start a jupyter notebook from a given point in the source code, so that the state of the interpreter in the notebook is from the line in the program where the notebook was started?

Comment: You might be also interested in [visual-logging](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/22/visual-logging-new-favorite-tool-debugging-opencv-python-apps/) tool.

Answer (score -1):

you can insert this in the function or class you want to start debugging

```
def foo():
    from IPython.core.debugger improt set_trace
    set_trace()
    # something else
```

then `Ctrl+Enter` to run the cell, and ipdb will stop at your break point.

ps. If you use **ipython** or **jupyter console**, magic method `%run -d [script.py]`
will run the kernel in debugger mode.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. It's a large application and I would like to start the jupyter notebook from the application. I'm not running the application from a jupyter notebook, so there's no cell to run.